# Display the result of a method in a Listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, wcf, listbox

I have created a WCF project where i am trying to display some information in a listbox. I want when i click on a button, it will call my method and display it in a listbox. My method works fine but i am unable to display it in my listbox. Here's the code i am trying:

```js
        $('#btnListBlob').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:50525/BlobService.svc/ListBlob',
                data: JSON.stringify(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).appendTo('#blobList')
                    alert('listed');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Some error Occurred!');
                }
            });
        });
```

I want the method i call in my URL to be displayed in my #blobList.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the data which you are appending. Data should be in the form of following:

```
<option value="5">item 5</option>
```

remember you are appending an HTML rather than appending just a data.

I would say put a console.log and try debugging the data received from server.

```
$('#btnListBlob').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:50525/BlobService.svc/ListBlob',
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
```

> console.log(data)

```
                $(data).appendTo('#blobList')
                alert('listed');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Some error Occurred!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few suggestions that you might find useful:

```
// only update the dom on click
// also use the new on() method
$('#btnListBlob').on("click", function () {
    $("#blobList").html(processData())
});

// separate the call and data processing
var serverData = {"fakeServerData":[
    {"data": "test data 1"},
    {"data": "test data 2"}
]};

function processData(){
    var options ="";
    for( var i = 0 ; i < serverData.fakeServerData.length ; i++){
        options += "<option>" + serverData.fakeServerData[i].data + "</option>";
    }

    return options;
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: I don't really understand what you have done and how i am suppose to call my method with this :/ can you please be more specific? Thank you

Comment: What I meant was don't try to do everything on that click. Use the processData() on success. I just simulated an AJAX call, with serverData being the result object of that call. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwsmihai/gof8m6dL). Feel free to build on this fiddle to show me exactly what you wanted to achieve.